# get compared value from in_array php

Tags: php

I have array:

```
$conditions=array("type","genre");
$type=array("Bars","Restaurant");
$genre=array("American","Irish Pub");
```

My condition is

```
$excelvalue='IRiSH PUB';
if(in_array(strtolower($excelvalue),array_map('strtolower',$$conditions)))
```

How should I get value of **"Irish Pub"** from array while comparing through in_array()?

Comment: `$$conditions` =/= `$conditions`. Use `array_search`.

Comment: `in_array` is not meant for comparing - you have `array_diff` and `array_intersect` to find the different and intersecting value between two array

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `array_search`. You also had a typo: `$$conditions` rather than `$conditions`:

```
$excelvalue='IRiSH PUB';
if ( array_search(strtolower($excelvalue), array_map('strtolower',$conditions)) )
{
    // some code
}
```